# Mongoose and Mongodb : $inc on Mixed Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create analyzing tool. It will read some sentence and process it and get some keyword for the day. After some time I would be doing same thing again. So every time i get it I have to save it and next time the same word comes I want to increase the count of the word by given value.

So for example I get content:{stackoverflow:2,question:5} first time I save that, next time I get content:{stackoverflow:3,answer:2} i should update the old record and the record will look something like this content:{stackoverflow:5,question:5,answer:2}.

I don't know what words are coming so i created content:Schema.Types.Mixed but $inc is allowed for only numbers.

```
{ [MongoError: Modifier $inc allowed for numbers only]
  name: 'MongoError',
  lastErrorObject:
   { err: 'Modifier $inc allowed for numbers only',
     code: 10152,
     n: 0,
     connectionId: 77,
     ok: 1 },
  errmsg: 'Modifier $inc allowed for numbers only',
  ok: 0 }
```

Any idea how to do it?

Update: My code.

```
for(index in wordsArray){
  var word = wordsArray[index];
  if(word!==topic && excludedWords.indexOf(excludedWords)===-1){
      if(slotLoc[word])
        ++slotLoc[word];
      else
        slotLoc[word] = 1;
  }
}

Words.findOneAndUpdate({slot:slot},{$inc:{content:slotLoc}},{upsert:true},function(err){
  if(err)
    console.log(err)
  else
    console.log("Saved Tweet");
})
```

Regards,
Jishnu

Comment: Can you update your question with your code that does the `$inc` update?  This should work fine.

Comment: Hi JohnyHK, I have updated the queston with the code.

Comment: Hi Joe, Thanks for the suggestion I'll give it a try but most probably ill stick with mongodb.

Comment: `content:$inc:{content:slotLoc}` isn't valid JavaScript, and what's the value of `slot`?

Comment: @JohnnyHK: Sorry I was trying different combination there and I copied in middle of the change. slot is a number where i decide it goes which slot.

Comment: In the `$inc` object, the value of `content` needs to be a number.  Isn't `slotLoc` an array?

Comment: @JohnnyHK : So how will i do it? I dont know what words I am going to get. If exists I just have to update the count with value passed and if does not exist just insert the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close, but you need to build up your `$inc` object's value using keys with dot notation instead of nested objects so that it looks like `{ 'content.foo': 1, 'content.bar': 2 }`.

So update your code to something like:

```
var inc = {};
for(index in wordsArray){
  var word = wordsArray[index];
  if(word!==topic && excludedWords.indexOf(excludedWords)===-1){
      var key = 'content.' + word;
      if(inc[key])
        ++inc[key];
      else
        inc[key] = 1;
  }
}

Words.update({slot:slot}, {$inc: inc}, {upsert:true}, function(err){
  if(err)
    console.log(err)
  else
    console.log("Saved Tweet");
});
```

Note that I used `update` instead of a `findOneAndModify` because you only need that when you want either the original or resulting doc returned.

Comment: With this its not saving the record. I have updated the question with schema details.

Comment: @neolivz4ever It did work when I tried it.  `console.log` your `inc` object to see if it's being created as you expect.

Comment: I am just trying to save a test object. {'console.test':100} as mentioned in the updated question. It tells its saved. But nothing get saved in DB.

Comment: @neolivz4ever Change `'console.test'` to `content.test` in your test object.

Comment: Thanks and sorry. Wrong copy paste mistake.